# is it possible to generate swagger metadata json automatically with flask-RESTplus?

Tags: python, json, swagger, swashbuckle, flask-restplus

I have created an api using the python library flask-Restplus and have it's associated swagger ui being exposed to e.g http://serverURL:80/api/v1/documentation.

Is it possible to expose this documentation page as a json somehow?
I know this is possible using the .Net library "Swashbuckle" (for e.g http://serverURL:80/api/v1/documentation.json would return the documentation in json format). I am looking for a way for this same type of functionality in python.

Comment: Are you saying that something like this: http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1 is not a json?

Comment: No that is a Json and that's exactly how I want my documentation page to appear in flask (as a json). So I want that same functionality with my python flask API but haven't found a library that supports this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this .json of the swagger ui is not generated in the documentation page but rather automatically generated the root directory with flask_Restplus library. for example "http://serverURL:80/api/v1/swagger.json" was the url which had this page instead of my documentation url "http://serverURL:80/api/v1/documentation". I didn't have to make any code changes for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to running the development server and opening the browser, here is some code to extract the Swagger specification as JSON:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

def print_swagger_file():
    with app.app_context():
        print(json.dumps(api.__schema__, indent=4))
```

Comment: To the downvoters: Could you please explain why you downvoted my post? As far as I can see, it is a perfectly valid answer to the question. (In fact, I arrived at this question precisely because I was looking for a solution myself and wanted something *automated* and *written in Python*.)

Comment: Although (as you say) this option may be unneeded for certain scenarios (using the browser onto <base_path>/swagger.json and get the JSON is an option), it is extremely useful for automating things. Moreover, I needed that because I had configured `decorators` in the API constructor and thus things were breaking. By doing this, I can automate the development and leave the authentication-required decorators in place.

Answer (score -1):

To get the swagger.json, go to the :/swagger.json you will get the swagger.json. Use this swagger.json to generate the documents .
Go to https://editor.swagger.io and add ur swagger.